# CodeIgniter query wont return correct data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I have two tables `customers` and `agenda`

What I'm trying to get is all customers for user_id and their next appointment.

This is how far I got , but this keeps returning a wrong date

```
        $today = date("Y-m-d");

        $this->db->select('c.firstname,c.lastname,a.date as next_appointment');
        $this->db->from('customers c');
        $this->db->join('agenda a','a.customer_id = c.customer_id AND a.date > '.$today.'','left');
        $this->db->where('c.user_id', $user_id, FALSE);
        $this->db->group_by('c.customer_id');
        $this->db->order_by('c.firstname', 'asc');

        $Q = $this->db->get();

        die(json_encode($Q->result_array()));
```

Here is a screenshot of the results

[image]

All these dates should be in the future otherways it should return `NULL`

**Note** : another small thing that might be causing this is that no matter how I join `"left"` `"right"` `"inner"` It keeps returning exactly the same results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your date comparison should be in a 'where' function and not in the join. Also the date should be inside quotes as Rocket Hazmat points out in his answer.

Comment: @coderodour: If he's using a `LEFT JOIN`, then adding the date comparison to a `WHERE` may give incorrect results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *quote* your date in your query.

```
$this->db->join('agenda a', 'a.customer_id = c.customer_id AND a.date > "'.$today.'"', 'left');
```

Otherwise your date will be interpreted as a number, such as `2017-03-28` or `1986` (since that's what you get when you subtract).

You can also do:

```
$this->db->join('agenda a', "a.customer_id = c.customer_id AND a.date > '{$today}'", 'left');
```

Comment: Omg, this is all it took to make it work! Thanks alot